# Ideal RAM usage in Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS?

Tags: server, ram, memory-usage

I have my ubuntu server setup at Amazon AWS.
Specs are-

RAM - 1 GB
Processor - Intel Xeon, a single core allotted to me.

When I login, I find that RAM usage is always near 42%, I have setup apache2 and PHP but I am in production mode, so there's no load at all!
Is 42% ideal or something is eating up RAM?
Thank You

Comment: 1 GB of Ram is not much. Also, memory used has nothing to do with server load. My Raspberry Pi running only Docker and Portainer for the moment uses around 300 MB, so 400 MB for system, Apache and PHP sounds reasonable. My other system running 12 containers in Docker with several NGINX instances and databases uses around 1,5 to 1,8 GB.

Comment: Probably some important amount is used by system (file) cache. Look at the contents of `/proc/meminfo` for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you don't need to start worrying about memory usage up until Linux starts using swap.  The kernel keeps things around in memory to help speed up the system (like caching the filesystem) but will smartly evict pages if/when its approaching needing to use swap.

You can determine the amount of memory free by either doing `grep MemAvailable /proc/meminfo` or running `top` to see the "avail Mem" entry in the header.  These represent what memory the kernel has available if needed (i.e. this does not include disk cache).